# Is there a way to get the storage account tier(hot or cold) through the account lever in azure storage?

Tags: java, azure

I know there is a way to get the account tier through the blob level, but I'm wondering if I can get it through the account level by using access name or key, since the tier is set when creating the storage account.

Comment: May I know if my answer helps?

Comment: Hi Jack, yes I got it working now using management library.

Comment: Now I'm trying to minimize the user inputs.. I'm trying to check if I can also get the client secret programmatically instead of hardcoding it? I'm still stuck on this and I'm not sure if it's  possible. I can't also find any microsoft document saying it is not. Would you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that you can specify the access tier of a blob regardless of the account access tier. So, if you want to get the exact access tier of a blob, you need to get it from the blob level.

However, if you just want to know the account access tier that you set when you created it. You can just use [Azure Management Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java).

1. Add an auth file. https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/AUTH.md
2. Manage the storage account resource.

   ```
   StorageAccount storageAccount = azure.storageAccounts().getByResourceGroup("Jack", "storagetest789");
   System.out.println(storageAccount.accessTier().toString());
   ```